# C# Получить поле наследника абстрактного класса

Tags: c#, ооп, классы

У меня есть абстрактный класс Part и я хочу получить доступ к полям его наследников. Я создаю объект наследника, но взамен получаю ошибку, что ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта, хотя в отладке переменная имеет тип наследника

```
public struct information 
    {
        public string structure;
        public string latin;
        public string functions;
        public string clinical_significance;
    }

public abstract class Part
    {
        public Crown cr;
        public Cerebellum cer;
        public Forehead fr;
        public Occiput occ;
        public Temporal tmp;
    }

public class Crown:Part
    {
        public const int id = 110;
        public information inf_crw;
        public string crown_part;
        public string lateral_intraparietal_area;
        public string ventral_intraparietal_area;
        public string medial_intraparietal_area;
        public string front_intraparietal_area;
        public Crown()
        {
            crown_part = "crw_part";
            inf_crw.structure = "crw_struct";
            inf_crw.latin = "crw_lat";
            inf_crw.functions = "crw_func";
            lateral_intraparietal_area = "crw_1";
            ventral_intraparietal_area = "crw_2";
            medial_intraparietal_area = "crw_3";
            front_intraparietal_area = "crw_4";
            inf_crw.clinical_significance = "crw_clinic";
        }

        private Part GetPart(int id)
        {
            switch (id)
            {
                case Crown.id:
                    return new Crown();
                case Cerebellum.id:
                    return new Cerebellum();
                case Forehead.id:
                    return new Forehead();
                case Occiput.id:
                    return new Occiput();

                default:
                    return new Temporal();
            }
        }
```

Здесь я использую класс `Part` для создания экземпляра класса его наследника и заполнить этой информацией форму, в режиме говорится, что `temp` имеет тип `Crown`(по-другому он даже не зашел бы в if

```
    public PartInfoForm(int selected_id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Part temp = GetPart(selected_id);
        //Console.WriteLine(temp.GetType());
        if (temp.GetType() == typeof(Crown))
        {
            label1.Text = temp.cr.crown_part.ToString();
        }
        //label1.Text = temp.;
    }
```

EDIT: Проблема даже не в том, что я получаю `NullPointerException`, а в том, как мне получить поля наследника

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привести к типу наследника и обращаться к полям.

```
if (temp is Crown crown)
{
    label1.Text = crown.cr.crown_part.ToString();
}
```

Но я не понимаю, как поля типа нследника оказались в родителе. Это обнуляет весь смысл абстракций. Другими словами у вас бардак в модели данных, обфусцированные названия членов классов и самих классов затрудняют понимание кода до уровня невозможного.